# Using a category ID to log all new channels name and IDs

Tags: discord.js

So I know that categories are classified as the parent with an ID and the channels inside the category are classified as the child of the parent. What I am trying to figure out is if after launching my discord.js bot, is there a way to note new channels made in that category? Particularly noting the channel name and ID if a new channel is made and meets the condition of being in that category. Any help is appreciated, I've looked everywhere and haven't found anything hinting at an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called whenever a channel is created, `#channelCreate`.

```
client.on('channelCreate', async channel => {
    //Do something?...
});
```

Also in the code above I have used `client`, so if you want to do something with guild, fetch it first.